# CSS issue in adjusting text in div

Tags: html, css

Here in the image Title "Accounts and Holding Disclosure in crossing the white line while DRF is way above the white line...

[image]

How can i put the text just above the line using css.

Html code is

```
         <div class="tabs">
            <img src="images/disclosure.png" />
            Accounts and Holdings Disclosure</div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <img src="images/drf.png" />
            DRF</div>
```

Css is

```
.tabs
{
height: 85px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
padding-bottom:7px;
}
.tabs img
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 70px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write:

```
.tabs {
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is simply not enough splace in the first block to apply the padding. The .tabs is 85px height, the image is 70px height with a margin of 5px top. So the remaining vertical space for your text is 10px only, and you add 7px of padding.

You need to reduce the size of the image in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

should be :

```
.tabs {
   height: 90px;
}
```